# Getting nil date in iOS9 when using "[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];" this format

Tags: ios, nsdate, ios9, nsdateformatter

Here is my code:

```
NSDate *currentdate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *selectedDate = [df dateFromString:SelectedDate];
```

this gives proper date in iOS8 but in iOS9 giving `nil` date Please help. thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `SelectedDate` ?

Comment: Set the formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *selectedDate = [df dateFromString:@"2015-04-02 10:12:12"];
It is working fine in iOS 9!

Comment: what is use of en_US_POSIX? i am using en_GB.

Comment: what is value "SelectedDate" you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This solved my problem.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you're writing it all wrong. Giving same name to both NSDate and NSString. Try this code, will work.

```
NSDate *currentdate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *selectedDate = [df stringFromDate:currentdate];

NSDate *newDate = [df dateFromString:selectedDate];
```

newDate and currentdate will be same though.

Answer (score -1):

If your `SelectedDate` does not conform exactly to the date format in your date formatter, the result will be `nil`. It appears that is your problem.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. There can't be an answer until the OP provides more info.